# " MySQL Service detected with wrong path " After opening xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, port

I install Mysql server in my pc to practice j2ee and after some days i uninstalled it and installed xampp for PHP development but it is showing port not free error.
I already try using `cmd` and deleting the `mysql` files in c drive but no use still my xampp is saying that `MySQL Service detected with wrong path`...

---

Error log:-

---

> MySQL Service detected with wrong path
>   11:08:46 AM  [mysql]    Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
>   11:08:46 AM  [mysql]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>   11:08:46 AM  [mysql]    Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
>   11:08:46 AM  [mysql]    Expected Path: c:\xampp\new1\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\new1\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

Comment: change xamp  mysql  port to other port.

Comment: I am new to xampp can you plz guide me to change the port in windows

Comment: open `my.ini` file, and you can see the `port` change that port

Comment: I changed it to 3308 and restarted the xampp, still it is showing the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure while editing the Registry, you put the value using quotes " " the way it was displayed in the error msg, other wise it will not work

The correct way -

"c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" MySQL

Answer (score 13):

As you uninstalled the MYSQL server your machine still has the MYSQL service in your windows services with the old path. To avoid MySQL Service with wrong path error goto,

> 1.Registry editor(WINKEY+R > regedit )
>
> 2.Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEMS > CurrentControlSet > Services > MySQL
>
> 3.change "ImagePath" with the Expected Path(in your case it is "c:\xampp\new1\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\new1\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql")  given in the error

after completing this steps restart your xampp

Answer (score 0):

I did some but not all of that. I stopped MySQL in services. Then went into the registry and renamed MySQL to the one I have installed separately to MySQL57. That worked for me.